# How and when a BLE peripheral name is set for the first time

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, hardware, cbperipheral

Changing peripheral name on hardware:

- When and how is it possible to change a BLE peripheral **name**?
- Is this something that needs to be written in the **firmware**? And if so how?

I am looking at some iOS client code and using the **CBPeripheral** to detect a BLE peripheral using the CoreBluetooth library. I can see an advertisement of my iPad where the name field has the mutable name "mm24 iPad" (which I can change from iTunes).

**I suspect that each BLE peripheral can be configured at production time with a default name and then modified subsequently using a BLE API**. Is this correcT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you understood about name is correct . **The name of the peripheral is Read-only property and you cannot change it**.  The name of the peripheral is written firmware.

If you have the control of peripheral code , you can create one writable/readable characteristic on which you can send the new name for the peripheral. And from next time you will get that new name .

If you dont have control on peripheral code then use one writable/readable characteristic to read and write the name of the peripheral . This is obviously not the real name of the device but for the end user it is like a real name of the device .